# styling a div with a specific ID

Tags: css, css-selectors

`#contentpage div`

Does this mean select the div that has id `#contentpage`?

I am getting some bad layout.  I am trying to select the div with the id `#contentpage`.

Could somebody also please tell me what the following css mean:

```
#myid div a
.myid a h
div #myid a
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#myid div a
<anytag id="myid"><div><a rel="match">...

.myid a h
<anytag class="myid"><a><h rel="match">...

div #myid a
<div><anytag id="myid"><a rel="match">...
```

If you would like to match a div with id #myid, then either ignore the fact that it's a div (ids are unique anyway) or match it as follows:

```
div#myid
```

Answer (score 1):

```
#myid div a
```

This will match an `a` within a `div` within an element with the id of `myid`.  When I say "within" I mean anywhere within at any nesting level.  The others are all the same but with different elements in different orders.

---

If you want an element with the id of `contentpage` you simply use `#contentpage`.  If for some reason you wanted to specify that it was a div it would be `div#contentpage`.

Answer (score 0):

if you want to modify the styling of the div with the id of contentpage then you would do the following

```
div#contentpage { //input styling here }
```

OR

```
#contentpage { //input styling here }
```

it also looks like you are trying to get at elements under the div these can be accessed in a number of ways but this is usually what I do

```
<div id="contentpage"><div><a></a></div></div>

#contentpage a { //stying }
#contentpage div a {  //styling }
```

Answer (score 0):

`#contentpage {color:red}` will select whichever element with id `contentPage`

`#myid div a` will select `<a>` elements that are inside `<div>` that are inside an element with id `myid`

`.myid a h` as far as I know there is no `<h>` element ? Without the `h`, it would select all links within any elements with the class `myid` (in this case myid is a dubious name, then, since its not an id per se)

`div #myid a` will select links inside of an element with id `myid`, but only if this element is within a `<div>`. It won't work if the element `myid` is a direct children of `<body>` for example